# Dereferencing double pointer, triple pointers, and so on

Tags: c++, pointers

Below is a sample program I created to play around with pointers.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void addOne(int** ptr);
void addTwo(int*** ptr);
void addThree(int**** ptr);
void addFour(int***** ptr);

int main()
{
    int* ptr = nullptr; 
    int x = 1; 
    ptr = &x;

    cout << "Original value of x: " << *ptr << endl;

    addOne(&ptr);

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

void addOne(int** ptr)
{
    **ptr += 1;
    cout << "After adding 1: " << **ptr << endl;
    addTwo(&ptr);
}

void addTwo(int*** ptr)
{
    ***ptr += 2;
    cout << "After adding 2: " << ***ptr << endl;
    addThree(&ptr);
}

void addThree(int**** ptr)
{
    ****ptr += 3;
    cout << "After adding 3: " << ****ptr << endl;
    addFour(&ptr);
}

void addFour(int***** ptr)
{
    *****ptr += 4; 
    cout << "After adding 4: " << *****ptr << endl;
}
```

The program above will give me the following output:

```
Original value of x: 1
After adding 1: 2
After adding 2: 4
After adding 3: 7
After adding 4: 11
```

Now focus on the addFour function:

```
void addFour(int***** ptr)
{
    *****ptr += 4; 
    cout << "After adding 4: " << *****ptr << endl;
}
```

Now what I did was I reduced the number of *s in the addFour function by doing this:

```
void addFour(int***** ptr)
{
   ****ptr += 4; 
   cout << "After adding 4: " << ****ptr << endl;
}
```

When I did the above code, it gave me the following output:

```
Original value of x: 1
After adding 1: 2
After adding 2: 4
After adding 3: 7
After adding 4: 010EFDE0
```

My question then is, what is the following statements doing since I reduced the number of *s:

```
****ptr += 4; 
cout << "After adding 4: " << ****ptr << endl;
```

Can someone please explain this for me?

Comment: What on earth are you trying to do?!

Comment: I'm trying to observe the behavior of pointers. This was discussed in class. I was just trying to understand what is going on.

Comment: @Omicron If you seriously want to write c++ code, best forget about pointers at all. For 99% of your real world use cases, you don't need them at all (no matter how many asterisks).

Comment: Please don't do this! You are never, ever going to use this in a real program. Nobody can handle four or five stars, and you probably need a double PhD to even get three stars right.

Comment: @BoPersson: Please see my answer and send me that double PhD at your earliest convenience.

Comment: It's the same as the difference between `*ptr += 4` and `ptr += 4`. If you can't work out what that difference is you shouldn't be using pointers.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Lol. My Professor was discussing this in class. He might ask question about it in the exam so I'm trying to play with it.

Comment: @Omicron Well, using pointers shouldn't be a primary topic for a basic c++ class curriculum, may be you're attending an advanced course.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It is a data structures class. I hate that we are not using the book though. We are merely using the lectures created by the Professor himself. We have the book written by Nell Dale C++ Plus Data Structures. It is a horrible book. Thus, I am forced to learn things on my own.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: But there is a big difference between not using multi-pointers because you don't know how to use them correctly anyway, and not using them precisely *because* you know all about them. In my opinion, the best programmers are those who use high-level constructs because they understand the *problem* which those constructs solve. I think someone who never attempted to write a toy program like the OP did here will also never appreciate `std::vector`...

Comment: Write your name on a piece of paper. The paper is now called name. Put the paper in a box. The box is now called name_ptr. "*name_ptr" is the act of opening the box to see what's in it. "*name_ptr = "Bing"" is the act of replacing the paper in the box with another paper with my name. Put the box inside another box called name_dptr; "*name_dptr" is the act of opening the second box to get to the first box. "**name_dptr" is the act of opening both boxes to get to the paper. Strictly nontechnical and, I hope, useful description.

Answer (score 3):

You reduced the dereferencing in `addFour` to four levels, but the function still takes an `int*****`.

Most of your code is irrelevant and can be reduced to something like this:

```
int x = 1;

cout << "Original value of x: " << *&x << endl;
x += 1;
cout << "After adding 1: " << **&&x << endl;
x += 2;
cout << "After adding 2: " << ***&&&x << endl;
x += 3;
cout << "After adding 3: " << ****&&&&x << endl;
x += 4;
cout << "After adding 4: " << *****&&&&&x << endl;
```

So far your dereference and address-of operations cancel out. But then you're asking what this is:

```
cout << "After adding 4: " << ****&&&&&x << endl;
```

Quite simply, you have not performed the final dereference so you're left with `&x`, not `x`.

And `&x` is a pointer. In the example above, you'd be seeing the address of `x` in memory, given in hexadecimal notation. In your case, your `ptr` has an unspecified value because pointer arithmetic out of bounds of an object has undefined behaviour, but in practice you're printing the value of the address of `x` plus `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: In other words the statements:                                                                           '****ptr += 4; 
cout << "After adding 4: " << ****ptr << endl;'                                             Are dealing with the contents of the triple-level pointer variable itself? And not the contents of the reference to the pointer ptr?

Comment: @Omicron: No idea what you just said, sorry. _"the contents of the reference to the pointer ptr"_ ??

Comment: What I mean is, does the statement:                                                                 `****ptr += 4;`                                                                                                             Add four to the address stored in the ptr pointer variable?

Comment: @Omicron: Pretty much. It'll actually add `4*sizeof(int)`, because that's how pointer arithmetic works. But yes. Technically your code has undefined behaviour because you're advancing the pointer beyond the object it points to.

Comment: @LRO Why undefined behavior? It is UB to dereference it, but doing arithmetic and printing the address is well-defined. And he is not printing the address of `x` but the incremented address of `x`.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès It is not well-defined. That is a common misconception. Check the standard! We need to stamp out this "you can do whatever you like with a pointer until you dereference it" myth.

Comment: Right I forgot 5.7-5 of the standard.

Comment: Even if it is to have better understanding, note that`&&&&&x`is not valid c++.

Comment: @Jarod42: Heh I'd actually forgotten that

Comment: I don't do c++ so I'll take your word for it.

Answer (score 1):

`addOne` receives the address of `ptr` that points to `x` and store it into a local variable `ptr`.

`addTwo` receives the address of `addOne::ptr` and store it in its local `ptr` variable.

`addThree` receives the address of `addTwo::ptr` and store it in its local `ptr` variable.

`addFour` receives the address of `addThree::ptr` and store it in its local `ptr` variable. Thus in `addFour` (second version):

- `*ptr` is `addThree::ptr`,
- `**ptr` is `addTwo::ptr`,
- `***ptr` is `addOne::ptr` and
- `****ptr` is `main::ptr`.

You then increment a pointer to int by 4, thus calculating the address of the fourth int starting from the address of `x`, and then print that address.

Of course, in the first version `*****ptr` is `main::x`, and you then increment int `x` by 4.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to visualize this graphically, you have:

```
P -> P -> P -> P -> P -> X
```

`X` is the value, `P` are pointers.
Every time you write `&`, you move to the left, and every time you write `*`, you move to the right.

So if you have `&&&&&x`, and you increment `****x`, you do this:

```
P -> P -> P -> P -> P -> X
                      \
                       > ?
```

You moved four levels to the right, and incremented the pointer there, which now points to a memory location after X.

Then you print `****x`, which is a pointer, because you moved four levels to the right.

Comment: Even if it is to have better understanding, note that`&&&&&x`is not valid c++.

Answer (score 0):

```
        // if you want to understand pointers this is my fave example

    struct block
        {
        int data;
        struct block *next_block;
        };

    struct block *block_head = NULL;

    add_block(int n) /* add n in the sorted position */
    {
        struct block *new, *prev = NULL, *bp = block_head;

        new = malloc(sizeof(struct block));
        new->data = n;
        while(bp != NULL)
            if(bp->data > n)
            {
                prev = bp;
                bp = bp->next_block;
            }
            else 
            {
                if(prev == NULL)
                {             
                    new->next_block = bp;
                    block_head = new;
                }
                else
                {
                    new->next_block = bp;
                    prev->next_block = new;
                }

    if(block_head == NULL)
        block_head = new;
    else
        {
        prev->next_block = new;
        new->next_block = NULL;
        }
}

// the above is how you usually do a linked list but it's messy and ugly
// not elegant
// the elegant way to do this is with a double pointer

    add_block(int n) /* add n in the sorted position */
    {
        struct block *new,  **bp = &block_head;

        new = malloc(sizeof(struct block));
        new->data = n;
        while(*bp != NULL)
           if((*bp)->data > n)
               bp = &((*bp)->next_block);
           else
               break;
        new->next_block = *bp;
        *bp = new;
}

// if you can understand the elegant version, you probably got pointers down cold.
```

Comment: I thought it might help the guy to give him a concrete real world use of a double pointer. You people need to relax a little.